# Meteor 1.3.3 on Mac running android: Android target: Android SDK not found

Tags: android, macos, cordova, android-studio, meteor

For a client of mine, I try to run the `meteor run android` command on a mac and I got the following message:

`✓ Java JDK
✓ Android SDK
✗ Android target: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.`

The situation so far:

- `PATH` is correctly defined with links to the tools and to the platform-tools, `ANDROID_HOME` is fine too
- The emulator and the SDK are installed with Android Studio
- `gradle` is not found either, the `tools/templates/wrapper` path does not exist, which make me suspect a bad SDK installation, yet Android Studio handles everything
- Meteor version is 1.3.3 for this project, and of course android paltform has been added to the project, which run fine on my Linux laptop

Verbose is not that verbose, in which situation Android SDK is okay and Android target is not ?

This is very hard to debug and I am desperate to find a solution, this issue seems unresolved in other related threads. Thanks for your help!

Comment: ¿Do you create an emulator in Android Studio?

Comment: Hi, yes the emulator has been created using Android Studio. Could it be related ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a bug due to the new version of the Android SDK Tools (> 25.3).
The solution is to go back to 25.2.x, the Meteor guide mobile page has been updated a few hours ago.

[See the related Github issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8464)

Links to download 25.2.5 version:

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-linux.zip
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-macosx.zip